# Why we need a workspace in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Why we need a workspace? For example, our codes are under file A, then we set our workspace to B(empty). But after we edit our codes, there is still nothing is file B. However, code in A has changed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a third-party tool.

Comment: @Laf Questions about programming tools are on-topic on Stack Overflow, unless it is about recommendation of such tool.

Comment: eclipse includes it's own version control mechanism which allows you to use local history. Also, the ability to support multiple workspaces allows you to separate projects and versions of projects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552266/eclipse-workspaces-what-for-and-why

Comment: @Pshemo even when it comes to explaning concepts about those tools which are documented in their own manual?

Comment: I believe you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how workspaces are (typically) used.

Comment: @Laf 99% of questions on SO can be answered by quoting some part of documentation/manual. But does it make them off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a matter of preference, it is used to help organize projects.

even if you change your workspace the code you edit will be saved onto the disk into the file it was originally created for.