# Projects not visible in Eclipse after Git checkout

Tags: eclipse, git

I initializing git repository in the eclispe workspace and added remote repositories from Github.  I did a git fetch and then checkout out a branch from the remote from within eclipse git view.  The projects that were visible in the project explorer and package explorer and no longer visible now.  Tried to import them using from file->import menu but I see a message  ***Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace***

I'm using Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2) version.  I noticed the same behavior with STS (3.7.2) also.  Is there a way I can get back the projects shown in eclipse again?

Answer (score 1):

> Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace

That is not related to git, and more related to how Eclipse is managing [its workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13552266/6309): it cannot accept two eclipse projects with the same name.

Try [switching to a brand new workspace](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-workspaceswitch.htm), and re-import your Eclipse project there.

If that eclipse project is in a local git repo, [share it with Git](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Sharing) and Eclipse will detect that existing git repo.

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/1/1d/02-TeamShareProject.png]  [image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/8/88/03-SelectRepositoryTypeGit.png]