# Minecraft Modding with Java and Forge installment

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, minecraft-forge

I already have Ecplipse and Java installed and downloaded forge. I also already have a Workspace in Eclipse. Now the guy I'm watching on youtube builds his tutorial from the ground up, so he creates a new workspace, do I also have to create a new Workspace or can I put my forge files into the existing one? If so, do I have to make a new folder inside the workspace, where all my other projects are?

Thats what it looks like right now (The crossed out stuff are my current projects):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/llxdG.png

Can I just drag the forge files from the zip package inside there or what do I have to do?

Comment: Additional details about Workspaces can be found here if you want more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552266/eclipse-workspaces-what-for-and-why

Comment: For the most part, you only need a new Workspace if you want to group up certain projects together or create separate configurations related to Eclipse such as key bindings or the compiler version. For your purposes, it may be good to have a specific Workspace for Minecraft projects for the sake of organization. But it's most likely not required.

Comment: Wait so I can make more than 1 Workspace? How do I switch between them in Eclipse?

Comment: If you select "File" from the menu in the top left, there's a "Switch Workspace" option near the bottom of the menu.

Comment: Nice, Thank you!

Comment: No problem mate.